# No suitable method found for requestLocationUpdates

Tags: java, android

This is my MainActivity.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener locationListener = new GetCurrentLocation();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, locationListener);
}
```

And this is my GetCurrentLocation.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class GetCurrentLocation extends Activity implements LocationListener {
    String longitude;
    String latitude;
    String cityName;

    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        //editLocation.setText("");
        //pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Toast.makeText(
                getBaseContext(),
                "Location changed: Lat: " + loc.getLatitude() + " Lng: "
                        + loc.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        longitude = "Longitude: " + loc.getLongitude();
        //Log.v(TAG, longitude);
        latitude = "Latitude: " + loc.getLatitude();
        //Log.v(TAG, latitude);

        /*------- To get city name from coordinates -------- */
        //String cityName = null;
        Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses;
        try {
            addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(),
                    loc.getLongitude(), 1);
            if (addresses.size() > 0)
                System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
            cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //editLocation.setText(s);
    }

    //@Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

    //@Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    //@Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}


}
```

The error I got is:

```
Error:(40, 24) error: no suitable method found for requestLocationUpdates(String,int,int,com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener)
method LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(long,float,Criteria,PendingIntent) is not applicable
(actual argument String cannot be converted to long by method invocation conversion)
method LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(String,long,float,PendingIntent) is not applicable
(actual argument com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener cannot be converted to PendingIntent by method invocation conversion)
method LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(long,float,Criteria,android.location.LocationListener,Looper) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(String,long,float,android.location.LocationListener,Looper) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(String,long,float,android.location.LocationListener) is not applicable
(actual argument com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener cannot be converted to android.location.LocationListener by method invocation conversion)
```

I am totally blank on which part of the code I should fix and I have tried to google but no relevant solution can be found.

Comment: Use this link, I personally found this very useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954421/android-cannot-resolve-method-requestlocationupdates-fusedlocationproviderapi/41567850#41567850

Comment: Use this link, I personally found this very useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954421/android-cannot-resolve-method-requestlocationupdates-fusedlocationproviderapi/41567850#41567850

Answer (score 11):

You are using the wrong `LocationListener` class. You need to replace this:

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
```

with this:

```
import android.location.LocationListener;
```

The `com.google.android.gms.location` stuff is for use with the `FusedLocationProviderApi` which is part of Google play services.

The standard Android location stuff is in `android.location`.

Also, you have `GetCurrentLocation extends Activity`. But it isn't really an `Activity`. You need to remove the `extends Activity` clause. This will then cause problems because you are calling `getBaseContext()` in some methods of that class. To fix this, have the constructor of `GetCurrentLocation` take a `Context` parameter and save that in a private member variable. Then use that when you need a `Context` instead of calling `getBaseContext()`.

In `MainActivity`, when you create a new `GetCurrentLocation`, you can do this:

```
LocationListener locationListener = new GetCurrentLocation(this);
```

passing `this` as the `Context` parameter (`Activity` extends `Context`).

Answer (score 1):

The error telling you that there is no overload method `requestLocationUpdates` that accepts parameters `(String,int,int,com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener)`

The closer method is

```
requestLocationUpdates(String provider, long minTime, float minDistance,
                       LocationListener listener);
```

So possible solution to fix your error is:

```
long t = 5000;
float d = 10;
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, t, d, locationListener);
```

Refer [Android LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) for more details

Comment: okay i have done that and i got new error which is Error:(23, 8) error: MainActivity is not abstract and does not override abstract method onLocationChanged(Location) in LocationListener