# Android cannot resolve method requestLocationUpdates FusedLocationProviderAPI

Tags: android, fusedlocationproviderapi

I'm attempting to follow the Android [Receiving Location Updates](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html) tutorial. The example code is [here on Github](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/LocationUpdates/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationupdates/MainActivity.java).

Everything is working except for this line:
        `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);`

It's throwing a `cannot resolve method requestLocationUpdates` error. I don't see anything in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html#requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener)), but I'm pretty new to Android so might be missing something :).

Here's the full code. Any ideas where I'm going wrong? Thanks!

```
package location.test.example.com;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ActionMode;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

public class LocationFragment extends Fragment implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    protected Location mCurrentLocation;
    protected LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    protected String mLastUpdateTime;

    public static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 5000;

    public static final long FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS / 5;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mLastUpdateTime = "";

        buildGoogleApiClient();

        if (NavUtils.getParentActivityName(getActivity()) != null) {
            getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_location, container, false);    

        return v;
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        createLocationRequest();
    }

    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();

        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        startLocationUpdates();
    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mCurrentLocation = location;
        mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getDateFormat(getActivity()).format(new Date());
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), location.toString() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.i("LocationFragment", "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() " + result.getErrorCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        Log.i("LocationFragment", "Connection suspended");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You have to use `LocationListener` for `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates's locationListener`

not

> android.location.LocationListener

but

> **com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener**

Comment: Should have noticed that one! Nice find

Comment: Nice one. The LocationListener of this problem should be changed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582370/how-can-i-use-google-maps-and-locationmanager-to-show-current-location-on-androi

Comment: Man, you are brilliant. Thanks

Comment: will this work if user doesn't have google play services installed?

Comment: Genius from hell

Comment: I'm using com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener but still have the same problem :(

Comment: Even if I imported the right one, I'm still getting an error: "error: no suitable method found for requestLocationUpdates(GoogleApiClient,MapsActivity)
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);"

Answer (score 11):

Import

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
```

instead of

```
import android.location.LocationListener;
```

Comment: perfect solution. Thank you so much

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
import android.location.LocationListener;
```

From

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
```

and
remove these override methods

```
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Importing `android.location.LocationListener` or         `com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener` is useless as the packages remains unused.
Implement         `com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener` inteface will do.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the import statement ,
Use
**implements com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener**

than just LocationListener/android.location.LocationListener.

It sure solved my problem.

Comment: Please explain your answer. How implementing this interface will fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

need update version of google play services 10.0.0+

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.0'
```