# How can I show current location on a Google Map on Android Marshmallow?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I want google maps to show the location of the user. I tried this code, but it did not work on Android 6.

```
private GoogleMap map;
LocationManager lm;
LocationListener ll;
Location l;

LatLng pos;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.start_layout);

    lm = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    ll = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            l = (Location) location;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    };

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.nMap);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    map = googleMap;

    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(lm.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);
    }

    pos = new LatLng(l.getLatitude(), l.getLongitude());

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(pos).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(pos));
}
```

Here are the permissions I've set:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: In what way did it not work?  Crash?  Wrong location?  Also check your logcat for any errors and post them here.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

**For using FusedLocationProviderClient with Google Play Services 11 and higher:**

see here:
[How to get current Location in GoogleMap using FusedLocationProviderClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44992014/how-to-get-current-location-in-googlemap-using-fusedlocationproviderclient)

**For using (now deprecated) FusedLocationProviderApi:**

If your project uses Google Play Services 10 or lower, using the FusedLocationProviderApi is the optimal choice.

The [FusedLocationProviderApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi) offers less battery drain than the old open source LocationManager API.
Also, if you're already using Google Play Services for Google Maps, there's no reason not to use it.

Here is a full Activity class that places a Marker at the current location, and also moves the camera to the current position.

It also checks for the Location permission at runtime for Android 6 and later (Marshmallow, Nougat, Oreo).
In order to properly handle the Location permission runtime check that is necessary on Android M/Android 6 and later, you need to ensure that the user has granted your app the Location permission before calling `mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true)` and also before requesting location updates.

```
public class MapLocationActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    SupportMapFragment mapFrag;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Map Location Activity");

        mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        //stop location updates when Activity is no longer active
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        mGoogleMap=googleMap;
        mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

        //Initialize Google Play Services
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //Location Permission already granted
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            } else {
                //Request Location Permission
                checkLocationPermission();
            }
        }
        else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {}

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {}

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        mLastLocation = location;
        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }

        //Place current location marker
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        mCurrLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        //move map camera
        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,11));

    }

    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
    private void checkLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Location Permission Needed")
                        .setMessage("This app needs the Location permission, please accept to use location functionality")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapLocationActivity.this,
                                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION );
                            }
                        })
                        .create()
                        .show();


            } else {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION );
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // location-related task you need to do.
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        }
                        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }

                } else {

                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        tools:context=".MapLocationActivity"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Result:**

Show permission explanation if needed using an AlertDialog (this happens if the user denies a permission request, or grants the permission and then later revokes it in the settings):

[image]

Prompt the user for Location permission by calling `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()`:

[image]

Move camera to current location and place Marker when the Location permission is granted:

[image]

Comment: LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this); - II tried your solution, I got stuck with this line of code saying "cannot resolve requestLocationUpdates"

Comment: @RoCk Make sure your import is `import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;`, see here for the imports: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31448567/4409409

Comment: Hey, IN my Caseno work is goin on.. Still image type is found.. I m using Sony Xperia 18API. Will this work in this?

Comment: I mean I m not getting my Location.. IN my app there is only map and Radio button.

Comment: @DanielNugent Do I have to enable wifi on mobile when using this?

Comment: @LalindaSampath It works best with both WiFi and GPS enabled. It will work with WiFi off and GPS enabled, but it will probably take longer to get the first location update since GPS actually needs to use satellites to locate you.  If you're testing with GPS only, be sure to go outside and walk around to test it.

Comment: @DanielNugent I'm using Geocoder class in the Android framework location APIs to locate Geo-locations. Seems like Geocoder needs an active internet connection to fetch an address. I think that's the reason my app doesn't work when WiFi is not enabled. Is this correct that Geocoder uses internet to fetch the address?

Comment: @lalinda Yes, Geocoder needs an internet connection to work. It can be either WiFi or cellular, but you need an active data connection.

Comment: **I recommend to use
//move map camera and zoom**
`mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,11));`
Insted of those 2 lines. It reduce 1 code line and works better.
His 2 lines not allways move camera to the current location.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, after struggling with a lot of different approaches, this one worked flawlessly. But I have one problem. 
When the app doesn't already have the Location Permission , and GPS is turned OFF, the Map doesn't zoom in to my Location or shows a marker (even when the permission are enabled ). So how can I ensure that giving the location permission also turns on the GPS , or somehow prompt the user to turn on the GPS ? Isn't that what onConnected in the above code do ? Thanks

Comment: @yankee for prompting the user to enable Location Mode, take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31816683

Comment: How would you show location that would be shown like in google maps app?

Comment: i follow your code and it's works perfectly but i want to add some marker(lon & lat both are there) along with my current postion marker in mapvIew...so how can i add it....
please help me

Comment: @techDigi You can add as many Markers as you want to as long as you have the lat/lon.  Just use the `map.addMarker()` method for each Marker.

Comment: How would you do this for a Fragment?

Comment: @TheLearner For doing this inside a Fragment, see my other answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41754169/4409409

Comment: @DanielNugent  This solution is flawless. I had never really understood how the check permissions worked and in my research, this answer and this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scySXsk9yRc) have been informative.

Comment: It is giving me an error "Cannot resolve symbol LocationRequest". How to deal with this?

Comment: @KaranThakkar Be sure you're importing the correct class: `import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;`

Comment: I'm getting error "can't resolve LocationRequest and LocationServices". I'm using this version of play-services  in my app gradle "compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.4'".

Comment: @piyushsingh See here for the relevant imports: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31448001/maps-api-only-loads-with-location-setting-gps/31448567#31448567

Comment: @DanielNugent I'm still getting error can't resolve symbol for both.

Comment: @piyushsingh I just loaded 10.2.4 into a maps project, and it works just fine for me.

Comment: @DanielNugent I don't know what's the problem with my code but in the location package only I can see places and * to import, can't import LocationRequest and LocationServices.

Comment: @DanielNugent resolved that error by adding compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.4 in dependencies. but I'm getting another error " can't resolve method" for this line LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this).  I'm using this code in a fragment.

Comment: @piyushsingh For an example of this code in a Fragment, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41754169/4409409

Comment: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet." - Whenever I try to launch application,I'm getting this issue,Could't figure out what was wrong

Comment: @kavie how did you resolve the error. Even I am getting the same error **`GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.`**.

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi Be sure that you have the call to `mGoogleApiClient.connect();`

Comment: Yes already did it inside onstart method. But still the app crashes. Showing getlastlocation is null

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi I don't have any calls to `getlastlocation()` in this answer....

Comment: I think we need to disconnect google api client in life cycle to reduce resource usage

Answer (score 13):

Sorry but that's just much too much overhead (above), **short and quick**, if you have the MapFragment, you also have to map, just do the following:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true)
} else {
    // Show rationale and request permission.
}
```

Code is in **Kotlin**, hope you don't mind.

have fun

Btw I think this one is a duplicate of: [Show Current Location inside Google Map Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41753706/show-current-location-inside-google-map-fragment/49473292#49473292)

Comment: Then you should use `googleMap?.isMyLocationEnabled = true`.

Comment: This was long long before Kotlin :) but yes, seems to be a good idea

Comment: It doesn't move the camera to your location.

It only enables the icon on map.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make sure your API Key is valid and add this into your manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />`

Here's my maps activity.. there might be some redundant information in it since it's from a larger project I created.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {


    //These variable are initalized here as they need to be used in more than one methid
    private double currentLatitude; //lat of user
    private double currentLongitude; //long of user

    private double latitudeVillageApartmets= 53.385952001750184;
    private double longitudeVillageApartments= -6.599087119102478;


    public static final String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        // Create the LocationRequest object
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
                .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds
 }
    /*These methods all have to do with the map and wht happens if the activity is paused etc*/
    //contains lat and lon of another marker
    private void setUpMap() {

            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitudeVillageApartmets, longitudeVillageApartments)).title("1"); //create marker
            mMap.addMarker(marker); // adding marker
    }

    //contains your lat and lon
    private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, location.toString());

        currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .title("You are here");
        mMap.addMarker(options);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom((latLng), 11.0F));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (location == null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
        else {
            handleNewLocation(location);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
                /*
                 * Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original
                 * PendingIntent
                 */
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // Log the error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            /*
             * If no resolution is available, display a dialog to the
             * user with the error.
             */
            Log.i(TAG, "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        handleNewLocation(location);
    }

}
```

There's a lot of methods here that are hard to understand but basically all update the map when it's paused etc. There are also connection timeouts etc. Sorry for just posting this, I tried to fix your code but I couldn't figure out what was wrong.