# Google maps don't show location button

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Google maps don't show Location Button.
It is my code:

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMyLocationClickListener,
        OnMapReadyCallback {
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        mMap = map;
        // TODO: Before enabling the My Location layer, you must request
        // location permission from the user. This sample does not include
        // a request for location permission.
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);
        mMap.setOnMyLocationClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMyLocationClick(@NonNull Location location) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Current location:\n" + location, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyLocation button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Return false so that we don't consume the event and the default behavior still occurs
        // (the camera animates to the user's current position).
        return false;
    }
}
```

I read some tutorials, but I didn't find answers for my question.`setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true)` is not show the button on the right corner of google maps. I added permissions ,but they didn't help.Can you help me, please?

Comment: did you enabled your gps? ,also have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34608517/map-setmylocationenabledtrue-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

put this line after the map initialization
like

```
 mMap = map;
 mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
```