# Method works in OnResume() but not in OnCreate()

Tags: java, android, oncreate, onresume

I have a little app to get the Location and then show it on the map.

In `onCreate()` I start the LocationService and the map. I then want to call my `setLocation()` method to determine my location and show it on the map.

If i call the `setLocation()` method from `onCreate()` it does not work and the toast gets shown. If i call `setLocation()` from `onResume()` it works. What could be the reason for that?

Source here: [Github](https://github.com/RatchetCoding/The-Other-Side)

Thanks for any help. If you need a certain part of the rest of the code just tell me.

Comment: We do not know what `mapActivity` is, we do not know what `GPSService` is, we do not know what `getPos()` on `GPSService` does, etc.

Comment: added the whole source

Comment: have you tried using the debugger in the service call with breakpoints to see why the returned location is null?

Comment: Also the way you seem to have it the GPS service is pretty useless since you access it directly from the activity using to a synchronous method call

Comment: It seems like the OnMapReady() gets called after setLocation, thus mapActivity is null,  altough I create the mapFragment first, what could be the reason for that?

Comment: @Override
    public void onMapReady (GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mapActivity = new MapsActivity(googleMap);
    } . In onCreate(), mapActivity is still null.

Comment: Take a look here for a simple example of a complete implementation of this functionality: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34582595/4409409

Answer (score 0):

Never create service instances yourself via the constructor. There is no reason at all for `GPSService` to exist, let alone be a `Service`. That being said, `getPos()` will return `null` until such time as you get a location fix. Exactly when that will occur is indeterminate.

Similarly, never create activity instances yourself via a constructor. There is no reason at all for `MapsActivity` to exist, let alone to be an actual subclass of `Activity`. That being said, the `mapActivity` field in `MainActivity` will be `null` until `onMapAsync()` is called. Exactly when that will occur is also indeterminate.

Hence, you cannot reliably call `setLocation()` from either `onCreate()` or `onResume()`. After all, you may not be able to actually get a location ever.

Moreover, your application will crash on Android 6.0+ devices, if your `targetSdkVersion` is 23 or higher, as you are attempting to get locations before you even *ask* for the runtime permission, let alone have it be granted.

Your `mapActivity.moveCamera(location)` call cannot be made until you have a location and you have a map. You will need to arrange to see, in `onMapReady()` and `onLocationChanged()`, whether you have both pieces of data, and *then* call `mapActivity.moveCamera(location)`.

Also, FWIW, your `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` `<uses-permission>` element is in the wrong place in the manifest. `<uses-permission>` elements have to be the immediate children of the root `<manifest>` element, not children of `<application>`.

Comment: Thanks first for the answer, I'm new to Android development, I'm haopy about such advice. So you suggest putting that all in the MainActivity and not splitting it up into several classes? How can i get sure everthing gets called in correct order?

Comment: @strange-matter: "So you suggest putting that all in the MainActivity and not splitting it up into several classes?" -- for the level of functionality that you presently have, I do not see where the extra classes are giving you any benefit. "How can i get sure everthing gets called in correct order?" -- well, to a large extent, that comes with experience. Technically, have `onMapReady()` and `onLocationChanged()` call some common method that sees if you have met both requirements (map + location), where that method then calls `moveCamera()` once both requirements are met.