# Android View InflateException error

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

So, I'm having a lot of trouble with the `android.view.InflateException` and I'm not entirely sure why. it happens when I try to load a Google Maps Fragment.

any ideas/help with this error would be greatly appreciated.

> ```
> 03-28 19:11:50.061 17870-17870/com.example.beng09715.restaurant_finder E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                      Process: com.example.beng09715.restaurant_finder, PID: 17870
>                                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.beng09715.restaurant_finder/com.example.beng09715.restaurant_finder.Cocktails}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3119)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3218)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:198)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1676)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837)
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
>                                                                                       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
>                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:770)
>                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:483)
>                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
>                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:450)
>                                                                                          at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2321)
>                                                                                          at com.example.beng09715.restaurant_finder.Cocktails.onCreate(Cocktails.java:19)
>                                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6500)
>                                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3072)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3218) 
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:198) 
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1676) 
>                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837) 
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
>                                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
>                                                                                          at maps.db.r.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                          at maps.cz.c.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.b(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.newMapFragmentDelegate(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.d$a.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.alldynamite:62)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:395)
>                                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.ah.b(:com.google.android.gms:179)
>                                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.b(:com.google.android.gms:100)
>                                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.ag.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms:62)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:395)
>                                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzc$zza$zza.zzs(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.zzzW(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onInflate(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.onInflate(Fragment.java:1142)
>                                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2287)
>                                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
>                                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:357)
>                                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
>                                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:80)
>                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:740)
>                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:483) 
>                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
>                                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:450) 
>                                                                                          at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2321) 
>                                                                                          at com.example.beng09715.restaurant_finder.Cocktails.onCreate(Cocktails.java:19) 
>                                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6500) 
>                                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120) 
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3072) 
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3218) 
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:198) 
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1676) 
>                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837) 
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
> ```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permision.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.V2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Home_screen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Breakfast"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_breakfast"
        android:parentActivityName=".Home_screen"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.beng09715.restaurant_finder.Home_screen" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.beng09715.restaurant_finder.Breakfast" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Menu"
        android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Lunch"
        android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AfternoonTea"
        android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Dinner"
        android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Cocktails"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_cocktails">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.beng09715.restaurant_finder.Home_screen" />
    </activity>

    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->

    <activity
        android:name=".MapViewer"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_map_viewer">
    </activity>
</application>
```

MapViewer.java

```
package com.example.beng09715.restaurant_finder;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapViewer extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_viewer);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
}
```

Cocktails.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/map"
tools:context="com.example.beng09715.restaurant_finder.Cocktails"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Comment: post XML of Cocktails

Comment: @Yazan added Cocktails.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your api key is not set up correctly, as you can see in the logs:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
```

First, change to the new format for the API key reference in the manifest.

Change this:

```
    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.V2.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

To this:

```
    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

Note that if you haven't done so already, you'll need to use keytool in order to get the SHA1 fingerprint for both your debug keystore, and the release keystore, and also set up the API key on the Developer Console.

For info on getting SHA1 fingerprints from the debug/release keystores, [see here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup#release-cert).

You will use these SHA1 fingerprints in the API key on the Developer Console:

[image]

Once you have your API key set up, put it in `"@string/google_maps_key"`, and you're all set.

Comment: Grand That has worked, with regards to the new way in which Google maps works, will it always take you to the Google maps app, opposed to loading a map fragment inside the application I am building?

Comment: @bdg Great, glad it worked for you!  As for the way Google Maps V2 API works, you can still have maps inside your app, it looks like your code should work for that.  For a more complete example, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34582595/4409409