# setMyLocationEnabled() error on Android 6

Tags: java, android, google-maps, location

I'm trying to make that when I load my map activity, a "my location" button will appear. This is my code, and the button which makes my activity to zoom in to my current location isn't appearing. What do I need to change in my code to make it work?

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
private static final String FIREBASE_URL="https://********.firebaseio.com/";
private Firebase firebaseRef;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private GoogleMap mMap;
SupportMapFragment mapFrag;
boolean bPermissionGranted;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps2);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    firebaseRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        bPermissionGranted = checkLocationPermission();
    }
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);





    }
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();

        if (mMap != null) {


            CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(32.065483, 34.824550));
            CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10);
            mMap.moveCamera(center);
            mMap.animateCamera(zoom);

        }
    }
}

public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
public boolean checkLocationPermission(){
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
            //  TODO: Prompt with explanation!

            //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);

        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}



 @Override
 public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay!
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }
            } else {
                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
                Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }

    }
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mMap=googleMap;

    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (bPermissionGranted) {
            //User has previously accepted this permission
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        //Not in api-23, no need to prompt
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

    firebaseRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.child("users").getChildren()) {


                String rightLocation = child.child("location_right").getValue().toString();
                String leftLocation = child.child("location_left").getValue().toString();

                double location_left = Double.parseDouble(leftLocation);
                double location_right = Double.parseDouble(rightLocation);
                String party_title = child.child("party/party_title").getValue().toString();
                LatLng cod = new LatLng(location_left, location_right);
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(cod).title(party_title));


            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simplified version of my [other answer that also requests location updates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34582595/4409409) .

The key is just to make sure that the user has granted you permission before you make the call to `setMyLocationEnabled()`.

It's also possible that the user has not accepted the permission prompt by the time `onMapReady()` is called (most likely on first launch of the app), therefore there's another call to `setMyLocationEnabled()` in the `onRequestPermissionsResult()` callback in the case that the user accepted the permission.

First, ensure that you have the permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml (outside of the application tag):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Here is a full Activity class that will work for you:

```
public class MapLocationActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    SupportMapFragment mapFrag;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            checkLocationPermission();
        }

        mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
        mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            //User has previously accepted this permission
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        } else {
            //Not in api-23, no need to prompt
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;

    public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
                //  TODO: Prompt with explanation!

                //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);

            } else {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted, yay!
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }
                } else {
                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

If you revoke the permission:

[image]

It will prompt again:

[image]

Comment: I've tried your answer, but there is an error message on every time this line is written: `mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);`. The error says: _call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should explictly check if permission is available (with 'checkPermission') or explictly handle a potential 'SecurityExpection'_

Comment: And its even not asking me a permission to use my locations in my phone.

Comment: @olash12345 I just updated the answer again to simplify it even more.  With the added checks necessary, there was no need for the boolean.  I just tested this on both a Nexus 5 with 6.0.1, and a Nexus 6 with 6.0.1, and it prompts for the Location permission, and then enables the MyLocaction button, which works as expected.

Comment: It is not asking me a permission. And also it is not showing the button. Do I have to call the function `onMapReady()` somewhere?

Comment: @olash. No, onMapReady() gets called after you call getMapAsync().  Not sure why it's not working for you, it works just fine for me.  Check your logs for possible errors.

Comment: I think I know what is the problem. The permission request dialog is not showing up for me and because of that it is not showing the location button. Why is the permission request dialog isn't showing up?

Comment: @olash12345 Do you have the permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml?  Also, check your logs again, there is probably an error being logged that will tell you what the problem is.

Comment: This is written in my logcat, maybe this is the reason that my permission requests aren't showing up? `I/Choreographer: Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.` @Daniel Nugent

Comment: I've solved my request permissions problem! See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36529635/app-requests-arent-showing-up/36557669#36557669
Your answer is working for me. thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

You are  using the same condition  in if and else  both blocks.

```
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
```

So, if your above condition is not true then how will be the same condition gets true in your else block. That's the reason 
 `mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);` never gets executed because your condition is false.

I guess what you want to do in else block is  to request for permissions if it is not there. So it will change like this -

```
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
   } else{

       ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, <request_code>);
    }
```

And implement `onRequestPermissionsResult` callback

```
 @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case <request_code>:
                if (grantResults.length <= 0 || grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                     mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }
                break; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey, I've tried your answer, and there are two errors appearing:
1) What are you trying to do in this line `case <requestCode>:`? It causes an error.

2) This line shows an error: `mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);` which says:  call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should explictly check if permission is available (with 'checkPermission') or explictly handle a potential 'SecurityExpection'

Answer (score 0):

Please write N instead of M  after Build.VERSION_CODES.

In this  line in your code:

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)

it worked for me