# Get current location in onMapReady in android using google locations API

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to display the current location of the user on the google map inside my app but I don't want to keep updating the location as the user moves. His initial location should be recorded and showed until he closes the app. I have written the following code for this:

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mLastLocation;
double lat =0, lng=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    buildGoogleApiClient();

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


}

private void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    LatLng loc = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(loc).title("New Marker"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(loc));
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        lat = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
        lng = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

The problem with this code is that I'm getting the `lat, lng` after the `onMapReady` function has already finished executing. I thought that one of the ways to correct this would be create an `AsyncTask` to ensure that the location data is retrieved before the map. However, I'm trying to implement this in a way that won't use `AsyncTask`.

Comment: i have similar code. i seem to lose my location  "mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);" if i restart the app and have no network connection? think it has to do with fusedclient not having lastLoaction on restart.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just move the code that creates the Markers from `onMapReady()` to `onConnected()`, and move the call `buildGoogleApiClient()` call from `onCreate()` to `onMapReady()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    //buildGoogleApiClient();

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    //add this here:
    buildGoogleApiClient();

    //LatLng loc = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(loc).title("New Marker"));
    //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(loc));
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        lat = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
        lng = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

        LatLng loc = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(loc).title("New Marker"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(loc));
    }
}
```

Although, note that you will frequently get null from the call to `getLastLocation()`.  You can use `requestLocationUpdates()`, and call `removeLocationUpdates()` when the first location comes in.
Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34582595/4409409), it has a complete example of exactly what you're trying to do.