# onMapReady latitude and longitude are null when app is loaded for the first time

Tags: android, google-maps

I am able to display the latitude and longitude on moving marker. When this `onMapReady` calls, the latitude and longitude sets to `zero`.

Here is the code:

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    Log.d(TAG, "OnMapReady");
    mMap = googleMap;

    mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
            Log.d("Camera postion change" + "", cameraPosition + "");
            mCenterLatLong = cameraPosition.target;


            mMap.clear();

            try {

                Location mLocation = new Location("");
                mLocation.setLatitude(mCenterLatLong.latitude);
                mLocation.setLongitude(mCenterLatLong.longitude);

                startIntentService(mLocation);
                mLocationMarkerText.setText("Lat : " + mCenterLatLong.latitude + "," + "Long : " + mCenterLatLong.longitude);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }

}
```

I would like to set `-34, 151` lat and long when i opened the app or else i would like to get current location when the app is opened. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Where you written current location code ?

Comment: How can i achieve this here? @HareshChhelana

Comment: Check out this : https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Answer (score 1):

You add this code in `onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)`

```
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
.target(new LatLng(-34, 151))
.zoom(13)   //optional if you want to zoom or not
.build();
MapFragment.newInstance(new GoogleMapOptions()
.camera(cameraPosition));
```

And to get the current location on map check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36659113/5212133)

Comment: Is it possible to get the current location here?

Comment: cannot resolve symbol camera

Comment: just check the edit

Comment: Working fine. How can i get the current location ?

Comment: added the link to answer check that answer works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Add below line of code in `onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)`

`mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(-34, 151), 12.0f));`

Comment: How can i get the current location onMapReady?

Comment: Check out the blog http://droidmentor.com/get-the-current-location-in-android/

Comment: If it helped you then please accept it so it could be useful for others as well.

Comment: How can i retrieve lat and long from mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(-34, 151), 12.0f));?

Comment: You can not get LatLong from that code line. You need to pass the LatLong as a parameter and you will get focus of that particular LatLong position