# google map not showing current location in andorid?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, gps

I want to show the current location of user on google map but as of now i am not able to show the location.I have a Fragment in which i am writing the code.

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        initGamp(rootView);



        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView;
    }
```

**initgmap function**

```
  public void initGamp(View root) {

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        // check if map is created successfully or not


    }


 @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia, and move the camera.
//        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
//        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
//        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        Log.i("MAP","BEFORE LOCATION");
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        Log.i("MAP", "AFTER LOCATION");
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
        if (location != null) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"not null",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            onLocationChanged(location);
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 20, 0, this);

        Log.i("MAP", "END LOCATION");



    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        Log.i("MAP","CHANGE LOCATION");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"chnage",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mMap.clear();
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));


    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
```

**All permissions:**

```
<!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Above code i have used for showing location but i does not working.I have also button of current location button on tapping that still i don't get current location.

Comment: have you given permission in manifest??

Comment: Yes i have given @VivekMishra

Comment: It looks like you're not requesting the Location permission at runtime, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582370/how-can-i-use-google-maps-and-locationmanager-to-show-current-location-on-androi/34582595

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to wait until the  [`onMapReady()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/OnMapReadyCallback) callback has occured before you request location updates. Once an instance of this interface is set on a `MapFragment` or `MapView` object, the `onMapReady(GoogleMap)` method is triggered when the map is ready to be used and provides a non-null instance of `GoogleMap`.

Here is the full Activity code that does what you need. Register a location listener when the activity loads then when each location changed event occurs.

Here is the sample activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,     GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

LatLng latLng;
GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
SupportMapFragment mFragment;
Marker currLocationMarker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

mFragment = (SupportMapFragment)       getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
mFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap gMap) {
mGoogleMap = gMap;
mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

buildGoogleApiClient();

mGoogleApiClient.connect();

}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
Toast.makeText(this,"buildGoogleApiClient",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
.addConnectionCallbacks(this)
.addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
.addApi(LocationServices.API)
.build();
}

@Override
public void onConnect
```