# Cannot see the blue dot and circle at Mylocation Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

I want google maps to show the location of the user centered at the map as at the image 1
[image: Blue dot and circle]
And this is my Fragment Code:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
GoogleMap googleMap;
MapView mapView;
View myview;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_layout, container, false);

    mapView = (MapView) myview.findViewById(R.id.map);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mapView.onResume();
    mapView.getMapAsync(this);


    return myview;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    googleMap = map;
    List<EscolasMaps> escolasMapsList = new ArrayList<EscolasMaps>();
    //buscarEscolas();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getActivity()
            , Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

}
```

}

But when I execute it at the emulator, or at my phone, I only get the map whithout anything as show at image2
[image]

Comment: Take a look at the permission request logic in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34582595/4409409

Comment: I've been see this answer several times and nothing work.

Answer (score 2):

Try Code samples of Google.

> The [ApiDemos repository](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos) on GitHub includes samples that demonstrate the use of location on a map:
>
> - [MyLocationDemoActivity](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/MyLocationDemoActivity.java): Using the [My Location layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location#my-location), including runtime permissions
> - [LocationSourceDemoActivity](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/LocationSourceDemoActivity.java): Using a custom [`LocationSource`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/LocationSource.html)

You can use the My Location layer and the My Location button to provide your user with their current position on the map.

> Note: Before enabling the My Location layer, you must ensure that you have the required [runtime location permission](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location#runtime-permission).

Enable the My Location layer on the map as follows:

```
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

> When the My Location layer is enabled, the My Location button appears in the top right corner of the map. When a user clicks the button, the camera centers the map on the current location of the device, if it is known. The location is indicated on the map by a small blue dot if the device is stationary, or as a chevron if the device is moving.

[image]

You can always check and compare your codes to the sample code to verify or check if your implementation is correct.

Hope this helps!