# Lates Google Maps V2 current location solution

Tags: android, google-maps

There are so many old and even more new solutions written to handle the "go to my current location" with Google Maps V2.

I am having trouble finding the correct one that works with the latest permission changes in Android.

I have a google maps app with a custom go to my location button that would:

- Only uses GPS
- Works with the latest android permission logic
- Moves the map to the device location when the above two are fine.

Does someone has a solution that will work now in mid 2016?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location) of Google Maps Android API, the location data available to an Android device includes the current location of the device pinpointed using a combination of technologies, the direction and method of movement, and whether the device has moved across a predefined geographical boundary, or geofence.

This is the 3 options that you can use with your app.

- Using My Location layer that provides a simple way to display the device's location on the map. It does not provide data.
- Using [Google Play services Location API](https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html) is recommended for all programmatic requests for location data.
- And using the [LocationSource](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/LocationSource) interface allows you to provide a custom location provider.

For more information, check this [tutorial](http://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/intermediate/android-map-app-showing-current-location-android/) and related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39431892/cannot-see-the-blue-dot-and-circle-at-mylocation-maps/39463702#39463702).