# Can't see my current location, the location button doesn't appear

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm developing an app that will show my current location in map. I read about it for current location I need to add following line in my code, and after it the location button must appear. But it doesn't work. Could you help me?

```
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

Here is my code.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements   OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready    to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(sydney)
                .title("Marker in MyLocation")
        );

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 40));
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.hakobm.currentlocation">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!-- Google Play Services -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Why you using   mMap.moveCamera if you want current location ?

Comment: if i understand correct , its move the camera to location where you are (or you wnat if  you gave cordinates)

Comment: Yes you are right but if you want to use MyLocationEnabled then remove move camera from their

Comment: i remved it , but nothing is changed , still i can't see my location

Comment: okay, you can use fused api for getting current location then set move camera to current location.

Comment: please check from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39314901/getting-latitude-and-longitude-in-30-seconds

Comment: thx, i will try and let you know

Comment: try this code. http://pastebin.com/j9nXwQha zoom levels are much over to that app

Comment: reduce your zoom value to 10 -14

Answer (score 2):

You got to remember that

> You can use the My Location layer and the My Location button to provide your user with their current position on the map.

Before enabling the My Location layer, you must ensure that you have the required [runtime location permission](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location#runtime-permission). You can check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39463702/5995040) from a related SO question and [How can I show current location on a Google Map](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34582595/4409409) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try out:
mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

Comment: this is not a answer