# How to get last location on googlemap?

Tags: android, google-maps

**CODE :**

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private Location mLastLocation;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "oh, no", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "test"+mLastLocation.getLatitude(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); #Here is what i want.
    }
}
```

After i get my location through `mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);`,

I want get the `Latitude or Longitude` of the result of `mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);`.

but above code returned

```
        FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.keepair.myapplication_maptest, PID: 15483
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference
at com.example.keepair.myapplication_maptest.MapsActivity.onMapReady(MapsActivity.java:48)
```

**Question :** Is there any good way or method?

I don't care whether your answer says not exactly how to get the `Latitude or Longitude` of the result of `mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);`.

If your answer do check last location information, it's ok.

I'll be also happy if your answer check last `clicked point's coordinates` or `setMyLocation's coordinates` on googlemap.

Please would you let me know?

Comment: Take a look at th answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582370/how-can-i-use-google-maps-and-locationmanager-to-show-current-location-on-androi

Comment: this might help you get your last location: https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the last location, from the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html):

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            mLatitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
            mLongitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!