# making a map location based android app

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, maps

How will I go about for building a map based app, app should use GPS to sense the user's location and render maps keeping that location as the center. Is there any easy framework or an api for building map based apps which scales very well. What are the best tools that are free. Also my android studio app slows down a bit. Im using 4gb ram. Is there any way to speed it up without increasing the ram.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582370/how-can-i-show-current-location-on-a-google-map-on-android-marshmallow

Comment: Google maps have many options, one been (mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);) which will show a device location icon on the map. But you need to click on the icon to show the device location. Thereafter it will track the phone on the map -- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location -- use this guide to make your app  Location-Aware -- https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html