# Why isn't setmylocationEnabled showing location button?

Tags: android, locationmanager, mapfragment

I am building a navigation drawer application with a google maps fragment in the main activity, when opening app the first time, user IS prompted to activate locations on the emulator, but my location is in the south pacific, and the setmylocationsenabled when set to true doesn't even show..

Summary
-Locationbutton not showing
-GPS location totally wrong

Thanks in advance

**Here is my code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,
    OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private DrawerLayout drawer;
private static final String PREFERENCES_FILE = "yourappname_settings";
private boolean NavDrawerUser;
private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private Location mLastLocation;


/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkLocationPermission();
    }
    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavDrawerUser = Boolean.valueOf(readSharedSetting(this, PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, "false"));
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = setupDrawerToggle();
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    if (!NavDrawerUser) {

        drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        NavDrawerUser = true;
        saveSharedSetting(this, PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, "true");

    }
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

}
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    //stop location updates when Activity is no longer active
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }
}
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mMap = googleMap;
    LatLng sthlm = new LatLng(59.334591, 18.063240);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(59.32548371429321, 18.08181381173199), 14.0f));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sthlm));
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //Location Permission already granted
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } else {
            //Request Location Permission
            checkLocationPermission();
        }
    }
    else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLastLocation = location;

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    //move map camera
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
private void checkLocationPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Location Permission Needed")
                    .setMessage("This app needs the Location permission, please accept to use location functionality")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION );
                        }
                    })
                    .create()
                    .show();


        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION );
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // location-related task you need to do.
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                    }
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }

            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
                Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}



private ActionBarDrawerToggle setupDrawerToggle() {

    return new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close
    ) {
        @Override
        public void
        onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {

            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void
        onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super
                    .onDrawerClosed(drawerView);

            // Code here will execute once drawer is closed
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_touristbureau) {
        mMap.clear();
        loopJsonData("bureaus.json", R.drawable.touristbureau);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_wifi) {
        mMap.clear();

        loopJsonData("wifi.json", R.drawable.wifiorange);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_bikes) {
        mMap.clear();

        loopJsonData("bike.json", R.drawable.bikers);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_hideout) {
        mMap.clear();
        loopJsonData("hideout.json", R.drawable.hideout);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_explainhideout) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, HideoutsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_atm) {
        mMap.clear();
        loopJsonData("atm.json", R.drawable.atm);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_bars) {
        mMap.clear();
        loopJsonData("bars.json", R.drawable.barikon);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_clubs) {
        mMap.clear();
        loopJsonData("clubs.json", R.drawable.clubic);
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

public static void saveSharedSetting(Context ctx, String settingName, String settingValue) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putString(settingName, settingValue);
    editor.apply();
}

public static String readSharedSetting(Context ctx, String settingName, String defaultValue) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPref.getString(settingName, defaultValue);
}
```

**dependencies**

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0'
```

**XML**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="336dp"
    android:layout_height="242dp"
    tools:context="com.example.abbbe.lostinstockholm.MainActivity"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

**Added:Permission**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: I just took another look at your code, it looks like you can get rid of the `startLocationUpdates()` function, as you are already requesting location updates in `onConnected()` for the GoogleApiClient.  Just make sure to call `checkLocationPermission()` from `onMapReady()`, take another look at this answer for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34582595/4409409

Comment: Jesus christ I feel so stupid.......... went through my XML files and I had placed the mapfragment on activity_main..., thank you for your help, it was I who was stupid lol