# Keep location centered at all times

Tags: android, google-maps, location, centering

I use next code [How can I show current location on a Google Map on Android Marshmallow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582370/how-can-i-show-current-location-on-a-google-map-on-android-marshmallow) in my application. How can I keep my location allways fixed on my center screen and just map do move?

Thanks for support!

P.S. I am a newbie on android programing and want to make an app for my hikings.

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: To keep location updates going, remove the call to `removeLocationUpdates()` in the onLocationChanged() override.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add textview and mapview inside framelayout tags then edit textview gravity property to be centered

Comment: I talk about GPS location. The user mark to be allways on center.

Comment: set static location instance in ur activiity , then call on onMapReady() within OnLocationChange method