# Why does my add marker button not work?

Tags: android, google-maps, button, marker

I am currently working on an Android studio app where I need a map.
In this map I have a button called, add marker. What I want to do with this button is to display a marker in my current location whenever I press it.

To do that I have the next method:

```
private void drawMarker(Location location) {
        if (mMap != null) {
            mMap.clear();
            LatLng gps = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(gps));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(gps, 16));
        }

    }
```

The problem with this method is that its parameter is Location location so whenever I initialize the app and press on it, my app will stop and an error will show. I think this is because my parameter should be View view.

This is the error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method drawMarker(View) in the activity class com.naluapp.naluapp.MapsActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'addMarker

I tried to resolve this by putting a variable Location location in my map activity but that does no resolve my problem. I am no good at this kind of language so I need of your help. Do you know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The `android:onClick` method you reference in an XML layout must have a `View` parameter, and the method must be public.

Just define a `Location` member variable in the Activity as show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34582595/4409409), and then reference it inside the `drawMarker()` method:

```
public void drawMarker(View v) {
    if (mMap != null && mLastLocation != null) {
        mMap.clear();
        LatLng gps = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(gps));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(gps, 16));
    }

}
```