# LocationManager not displaying location in GoogleMap

Tags: android, google-maps, locationmanager

I am trying to build my first android app that tracks the users location. I am trying to achieve this with the following java code in my Maps Activity Class:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
LocationManager locationManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                double longitude = location.getLongitude();

                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
                try {
                    List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                    String str = addressList.get(0).getLocality();
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(str));
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10.2f));
                }catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            }
        });
    }else if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                double longitude = location.getLongitude();

                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
                try {
                    List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                    String str = addressList.get(0).getLocality();
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(str));
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10.2f));
                }catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    //LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

And the following permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

However my Android phone and emulator only display the global maps view.
The application does the API call and request everything it needs, but the information doesn't get displayed.

[image]

Also when just placing markers on the map in void `onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)` it does work.

I am testing my application on a Samsung Galaxy S5 and an emulated Nexus 5X.

Compile version: 7.1.1
Build Tools Version 26.0.2

Comment: try this for getting location https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45699971/fusedlocationapi-getlastlocation-is-always-null-even-oncreated?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Did you grant ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission for your application (not only in Manifest but on runtime)? Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46570554/6950238) answer.