# android: Can't add current location on map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-maps-v2, android-gps

I'm having trouble putting my current/updated location on the map which has other data. please see the image below. I need it because I will do a distance between the vehicle location and my current location, anyways how to do it? this activity is extended by fragment. I really need your help.

[image]

This is my `OnMapReady`:

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMapProximity = googleMap;
    mMapProximity.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
    mMapProximity.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);

    setUpMap();
}
private void setUpMap() {
    mMapProximity.clear();
    mMapProximity.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    mMapProximity.setIndoorEnabled(true);
    mMapProximity.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
    mMapProximity.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);

    final Double lati = Double.parseDouble(latitudeProxListMap);
    final Double longi = Double.parseDouble(longitudeProxListMap);

    m = mMapProximity.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(lati, longi))
            .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin_logo))
            .visible(true));

    mMapProximity.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            marker.showInfoWindow();
        }
    });

    mMapProximity.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lati, longi), 17.0f));

    mMapProximity.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

            if (marker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
                marker.hideInfoWindow();
            } else {
                marker.showInfoWindow();
            }

            return true;
        }
    });

    mMapProximity.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MarkerInfoWindowAdapter());

    m.showInfoWindow();
}


class MarkerInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

        View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_vehicle_list_map, null);
        TextView title =v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView snippet =v.findViewById(R.id.snippet);
        snippet.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        title.setText("Location: " + location);
        return v;
    }

}
```

Comment: what kind of trouble you are facing ?

Comment: hi @VivekMishra, putting my current location on the map plus the screenshot above

Comment: where are you adding your location on map. I can only see you are adding a marker on the map.

Comment: my plan is to see the location of the vehicle and my current location, computing how many minutes will i travel to get on my vehicle's location and add polyline. just like on the GRAB app

Comment: In your current code that you have posted you haven't done anything that will show current location.

Comment: yes as of now,  my brain is turning around thinking on how to add it

Comment: There is not need to turn your brain around. A little google search is enough for that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582370/how-can-i-show-current-location-on-a-google-map-on-android-marshmallow

Comment: `myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);` add this line to show current location blue marker **Make sure it has all the required permissions**

Comment: im having error on this

Comment: ` if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) `

Comment: but i had put it on my manifest

Comment: i tried to replace "this" to getContext, the output is the map is located at 0,0

Comment: i tried the code but its not working, it wants to check permission. but i already declared permissions in my manifest

Answer (score 1):

Implement LocationListener in your activity and than in onLocationChange method update the marker with the current location values. That will put a marker on the current location.