# Set Current Location

Tags: java, android

Is this something that is updated and need to be done with different method or something else?

**I want to get my current location on Google Maps what am doing right now is as follows.**

Creating GoogleMaps Activity,
Download GooglePlay Services from Android SDK Manager,
Giving Permissions in AndroidManifest for Internet and Location,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Giving permission to use my location in `OnMapReady`

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    mMap.setMapType(googleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}
```

When i try to run this code at my device `LG Spirit H440` I doesn't get what i expect to get, it should give me the option to get my current location with blue dot on the maps.

I have created also `API KEY` in the Google API's console.

**What am i doing wrong?**

Comment: At which API level you were running?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I show current location on a Google Map on Android Marshmallow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582370/how-can-i-show-current-location-on-a-google-map-on-android-marshmallow)

Comment: @GursheeshSingh Am running on API Level 23 6.0 or higher

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mMap = googleMap;


            locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    mMap.clear();
                    LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title("Your Location"));
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(userLocation));
                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

                }
            };

if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},1);
            } else {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
                Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                mMap.clear();
                LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), lastKnownLocation.getLongitude());
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title("Your Location"));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(userLocation));
            }
```

And onRequestPermissionsResult:

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Also as you created API key I believe you included it in AndroidManifest.

Source Rob Percival / Nick Walter.

Comment: Thank you for your method, atleast started to ask for the permissions, but this somehow crashes the app. `Unfortunately [app_name] has stopped.`

Comment: Show a logcat please

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference
                                                                                         at com.example.stefan.example.MapsActivity.onMapReady(MapsActivity.java:73)`
Line 73 is `LatLng userLocation`

Comment: BTW yes i did include `API KEY` in the AndroidManifest also created couple of others API KEY's for testing but still no success.