# cannot see my location on map

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm making an application and I created a map activity in this app, where I'd like to see the location of my phone. The problem is when opening the app, I only see the map and no marker, no location of me.

I assume there's something wrong with the permissions, but I handled them and requested all of them. What can be the mistake?

Thanks

```
public class AllLoxMap extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    LocationManager lm;
    LocationListener ll;

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission
                        .ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);

                    Location lastKnownLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager
                            .GPS_PROVIDER);

                    if (lastKnownLocation != null) {
                        updateMap(lastKnownLocation);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_lox_map);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        lm = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        ll = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                updateMap(location);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

            }
        };

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission
                .ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission
                    .ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
        } else {
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);

            Location lastKnownLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            if (lastKnownLocation != null) {
                updateMap(lastKnownLocation);
            }
        }
    }

    public void updateMap(Location location) {

        LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

        mMap.clear();
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title("Marker"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(userLocation));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is location from API is not null?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I restarted the app for a few times, waited and once the marker showed up.

Comment: You would get a location faster if you request the Network provider in addition to the GPS provider.  You can also use the location functionality from Google Play Services, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582370/how-can-i-show-current-location-on-a-google-map-on-android-marshmallow