# button click show current location in google map

Tags: android, google-maps

Hi i am new in android developing. This is my scenario Button click show current location in Google Map fragment in my application.

Now i did button click showing current location `lattitude` and `longitude`.

this is my code:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
        android:text="Start" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textSize="16dp"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.hello.sampleapp;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final int REQUEST_LOCATION = 1;

    Button button;
    TextView textView;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    String lattitude,longitude;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION);

        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_location);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_location);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            buildAlertMessageNoGps();

        } else if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            getLocation();
        }
    }


    private void getLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
                (MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION);

        } else {
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            Location location1 = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            Location location2 = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager. PASSIVE_PROVIDER);

            if (location != null) {
                double latti = location.getLatitude();
                double longi = location.getLongitude();
                lattitude = String.valueOf(latti);
                longitude = String.valueOf(longi);

                textView.setText("Your current location is"+ "\n" + "Lattitude = " + lattitude
                        + "\n" + "Longitude = " + longitude);

            } else  if (location1 != null) {
                double latti = location1.getLatitude();
                double longi = location1.getLongitude();
                lattitude = String.valueOf(latti);
                longitude = String.valueOf(longi);

                textView.setText("Your current location is"+ "\n" + "Lattitude = " + lattitude
                        + "\n" + "Longitude = " + longitude);


            } else  if (location2 != null) {
                double latti = location2.getLatitude();
                double longi = location2.getLongitude();
                lattitude = String.valueOf(latti);
                longitude = String.valueOf(longi);

                textView.setText("Your current location is"+ "\n" + "Lattitude = " + lattitude
                        + "\n" + "Longitude = " + longitude);
                String url = "https://iradivi.com/test/?latitude=" + lattitude +"&longitude=" + longitude;


            }else{

                Toast.makeText(this,"Unble to Trace your location",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    }

    protected void buildAlertMessageNoGps() {

        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Please Turn ON your GPS Connection")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

}
```

sorry for the question, i don't know how to ask this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I show current location on a Google Map on Android Marshmallow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582370/how-can-i-show-current-location-on-a-google-map-on-android-marshmallow)

Comment: https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/intermediate/android-map-app-showing-current-location-android/

Comment: Using lastKnownLocation() may not give you the current location of the device. But question is not clear, do you want to show location on the Google Maps application already installed on device or do you want to add Maps to your application?

Comment: @MuhammedKadirYücel i want to add map in my application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to get address corresponding to the latitude and longitude

```
Geocoder geocoder;
List<Address> address;
geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

address = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
```

then use this

```
String city = address.get(0).getLocality();
String state = address.get(0).getAdminArea();
```

Comment: Can you please tell me  where i want to add this code.

Answer (score 1):

use this method

```
public void setUpCurrentLocation(double latitude, double longitude) {
    if (latitude == 0 || longitude == 0)
        return;
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, AppConstants.MAP_MAX_ZOOM);
    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the your comment, you need Google Maps in your project. You can add Google Maps activity in your application easily with Android Studio. **File > New > Google > Google Maps Activity** will add a new activity that has Google Maps fragment inside. You can add thid fragment into your existing activities. But first, you [need to get a Google Developers API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup) for showing Google Maps inside your application. There are two ways of showing current location of user:

**First way**

You can get location manually and show it with a marker on Maps

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    LatLng currentLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentLocation)
            .title("Current Location"));
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(currentLocation));
}
```

You can find full guide and documentation in [here.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map-with-marker)

**Second way**

You can enable current location feature in Google Maps in your application. Make sure that you have location permissions.

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i things used to google service location.used below class to get current location and other information ...
add below dependency in gradle file.

```
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.0'
```

then after used below class ..

```
public class GPSController  implements
    LocationListener,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
```

{
    OnLocationUpdateListener onLocationUpdateListener;
    public final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

```
private FusedLocationProviderApi fusedLocationProviderApi = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi;
GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
Location mCurrentLocation;
private static long INTERVAL = 1000 * 10;
private static long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000 * 5;
FragmentActivity mActivity;
private boolean isLiveUpdate = false;


PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result;


/**
 * Checking permission and connect with Google Location service
 * @param activity
 */
public GPSController(FragmentActivity activity) {

    this.mActivity = activity;
    if(PermissionManager.checkPermission(mActivity,PermissionManager.ACCESS_LOCATION))
    {
        if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
            CustomLogHandler.printInfolog("checking googleplayservice : ", "false");
            ((BaseActivity)mActivity).showAlertDialog(mActivity, mActivity.getString(R.string.app_name), mActivity.getString(R.string.play_service_not_found));
        } else {
            CustomLogHandler.printInfolog("checking googleplayservice : ", "true");
            createLocationRequest();
            initFuseAPI();

        }
    }
    else
    {
        PermissionManager.askForPermission(PermissionManager.ACCESS_LOCATION,mActivity);
    }

}

public void connectForLocation()
{
    createLocationRequest();
    initFuseAPI();
}

/**
 * Turn on Live update of location on given interval
 * @param value
 * @param INTERVAL
 * @param FASTEST_INTERVAL
 */
public void turnOnLiveUpdate(boolean value,long INTERVAL,long FASTEST_INTERVAL)
{
    isLiveUpdate = value;
    this.INTERVAL = INTERVAL;
    this.FASTEST_INTERVAL = FASTEST_INTERVAL;
}

/**
 * Turn off live update of location
 */
public void turnOffLiveUpdate()
{
    isLiveUpdate = false;
}

/**
 * Disconnect from Google location service
 */
public void disconnect()
{
    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStop fired ..............");
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
        Log.d(TAG, "isConnected ...............: " +googleApiClient.isConnected());
    }catch (Throwable throwable)
    {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Resume Location update service if stopped
 */
public void onResumeUpdate()
{
    try {
        if(googleApiClient != null) {
            if (googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                startLocationUpdates();
                Log.d(TAG, "Location update resumed .....................");
            }
        }
    }catch (Throwable throwable)
    {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public void setLocatonUpdateListener(OnLocationUpdateListener onLocationUpdateListener)
{
    this.onLocationUpdateListener  = onLocationUpdateListener;
}

/**
 * Create location update request
 */
protected void createLocationRequest() {
    try {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }catch (Throwable throwable)
    {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
    }
}


/**
 * Initialize google location service
 */
void initFuseAPI()
{
    try
    {
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mActivity)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
        Log.d(TAG, "initFuseAPI fired ..............");
        googleApiClient.connect();
    }catch (Throwable throwable)
    {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
    }
}


/**
 * Check Google location service is available or not
 * @return
 */
private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(mActivity);
    if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status) {
        return true;
    } else {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, mActivity, 0).show();
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * called when connected with google location service
 * @param bundle
 */
@Override
public void onConnected( Bundle bundle) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnected - isConnected ...............: " + googleApiClient.isConnected());
    LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) mActivity.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );
    boolean statusOfGPS = manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if(statusOfGPS) {
        startLocationUpdates();
    }else
    {
        enableGpsService();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed( ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

/**
 * Location update received here
 * @param location
 */
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Firing onLocationChanged..............................................");
    mCurrentLocation = location;
    SetLocation();
}


void enableGpsService()
{
    try
    {
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
        result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());
        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult( LocationSettingsResult locationSettingsResult) {
                final Status status = locationSettingsResult.getStatus();
                switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                        //already connected to GPS
                        startLocationUpdates();
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by
                        // showing the user a dialog.
                        try {
                            status.startResolutionForResult(mActivity, PermissionManager.REQUEST_LOCATION);
                            startLocationUpdates();
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            // Ignore the error.
                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        //redirect user to setting screen, manually user can enble GPS
                        mActivity.startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }catch (Throwable throwable)
    {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
    }
}





/**
 * Request location update service
 */
public void startLocationUpdates()
{
    try {
        //check required even you checked it previously
        if (PermissionManager.checkPermission(mActivity, PermissionManager.ACCESS_LOCATION))
        {
            fusedLocationProviderApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
            Log.d(TAG, "Location update started ..............: ");
        } else {
            PermissionManager.askForPermission(PermissionManager.ACCESS_LOCATION, mActivity);
        }
    }catch (Throwable throwable)
    {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Stop location update
 */
public void stopLocationUpdates() {
    try {
        if(googleApiClient != null) {
            fusedLocationProviderApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                    googleApiClient, this);
            Log.d(TAG, "Location update stopped .......................");
        }
    }catch (Throwable throwable)
    {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
    }
}


/**
 * set location values received
 */
private void SetLocation()
{
    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "UI update initiated .............");
        if (null != mCurrentLocation) {
            onLocationUpdateListener.onLocationUpdate(mCurrentLocation);

            /**isLiveUpdate = true for Live update **/

            if (!isLiveUpdate) {
                fusedLocationProviderApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient,this);
            }
            googleApiClient.disconnect();

            //mCurrentLocation.getAccuracy()
            //mCurrentLocation.getProvider()

        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "location is null ...............");
        }
    }catch (Throwable throwable)
    {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Location getLocation(){
    return mCurrentLocation;
}
public static List<Address> getAddress(Double mLat, Double mLang, Context context)
{
    List<Address> addresses = null;
    try
    {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(mLat, mLang, 1);
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return  addresses;
}

/**
 * For receive location update
 */
public interface OnLocationUpdateListener {
     void onLocationUpdate(Location mCurrentLocation);
}
```

}

then after intialized this class into main activity and get current location lat and long value..

```
public class LocationActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements GPSController.OnLocationUpdateListener{

private static final int REQUEST_LOCATION = 1;

private GPSController gpsController;
Button button;
TextView textView;
LocationManager locationManager;
String lattitude,longitude;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.location_layout);
    gpsController = new GPSController(getActivity());
    gpsController.setLocatonUpdateListener(this);

}
@Override
public void onLocationUpdate(Location mCurrentLocation) {
    CURRENT_LET = String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude());
    CURRENT_LANG = String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
 }
```

}