# Not able to get current location in real devices

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, locationlistener

I need lat long of current location.I am getting lat long on emulator but not on real devices though my gps is on.

This is how I am getting current location.

```
 public void getLocation() {
        try {

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(listener, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) ==
                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 5, this);
                Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                Logger.log("LastKnownLocation"+location);
                gps_enabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                Logger.log("GPSEnabled"+gps_enabled);


            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {
                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION },
                        1);
            }

        }
        catch(SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

LocationListener listener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Current location"+ location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Logger.log("Current location"+ location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude());
        drawMarker(location);
    }
```

Comment: `(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 5, this);`. Change `this` to `listener`.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582370/how-can-i-show-current-location-on-a-google-map-on-android-marshmallow