# Can't get my location on google map API

Tags: android, google-maps

I have been trying to make Google maps display my current location, but it just shows me the whole map. Please how do I go about this, here is my code

```
 @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

        }else{
            checkLocationPermission();
        }
    }

    mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}

private void checkLocationPermission() {
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("give permission")
                    .setMessage("give permission message")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(WorkerMap.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
                        }
                    })
                    .create()
                    .show();
        }
        else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(WorkerMap.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
        }
    }
}
LocationCallback mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback(){
    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
        for(Location location : locationResult.getLocations()){
            if(getApplicationContext()!=null){
                mLastLocation = location;

                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());

                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));
            }
        }
    }
};
```

It's supposed to get my current location, but it's not doing that. What might be wrong please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I show current location on a Google Map on Android Marshmallow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582370/how-can-i-show-current-location-on-a-google-map-on-android-marshmallow)

Comment: The Fused Location API used in the the answer you directed me to is deprecated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You must to call this

```
mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

after you will get permissions from user, for example in function `onRequestPermissionsResult`.

2) Try to use `mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()` before you will make your request.

3) on which device you test this code?